# C++/CLI Visual C++ 2010 Express - Drawing different shapes inside one panel

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I got a problem. There is panel1 which i want to use as my paiting window. And i also have 2 buttons. One should draw "fillRectangle" in the middle of panel and second one should draw "fillellipse" next to it. I dont have the problem with drawing itself

```
Color aColor = Color::FromArgb( 255, 0, 0 ); 
SolidBrush^ aBrush = gcnew SolidBrush(aColor);
Rectangle rect = Rectangle(x, y, 10, 10);
e->Graphics->FillEllipse(aBrush, rect);
```

But i want to know, how to make that pressing each button draws different shape inside panel. Do i need to put both, ellipse and rectangle in panel1_Paint and use flags like...

```
if(ellip == 1) FillEllipse; 
if(recta == 1) FillRectangle
```

which are set using buttons? I hoped i can code drawing part inside button or function, and then somehow refer to that panel. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the buttons to have their own painting routines, then they draw themselves and your panel is unnecessary, in terms of drawing anyway, they'll have their own canvas.

If you want a panel that draws  shapes on itself dependant on some property, then yes you go down something like the route you suggested, though I'd be tempted by some sort of shape class even if it wasn't a control. Would make adding other shapes or more of a shape much easier.

You could have panel carry a collection of shapes that implement say IDraw which takes a Graphics reference, and then just iterate through them and call it with Panel1's graphics instance.

If it was me though particulary if I wanted enabled, visible, tab, click etc. I'd have a ShapedButton Control.